# Solve won't return an answer for a set of four equations

Tags: equation-solving, homework

So I was doing my homework and this system popped up, so I was trying to solve it but *Mathematica* has just been stuck with it for two days. It won't give me an answer. 
I am trying to get the code to use it in MATLAB, but I first need a set of solutions without my initial conditions for `d`, `r1`, `r2` and `q`.

```
r4 = Sqrt[xB^2 + d^2];
r5 = Sqrt[xB^2 + (d - r1)^2];
r6 = r4 - r3;
f1 = Sin[q] + r1 - r3 Sin[T1];
f2 = Cos[q] - r3 Cos[T1];
f3 = Sin[q] + r6 Sin[T1] - r5 Sin[T2];
f4 = Cos[q] + r6 Cos[T1] - r5 Cos[T2];
s = Solve[{f1, f2, f3, f4} == 0, {r3, xB, T1, T2}]
```

Comment: I would suggest trying the Weierstrass substitution for `T1` and `T2` so that you have a fully algebraic set of equations.

Comment: Nope, still wont solve it hehehe

Comment: Using `Reduce` instead of `Solve` will give you some information in a minute, `Solve` is more generally suited to polynomial problems while Reduce can attack transcendentals. But if this is a homework problem then I think there is something deeply wrong

Comment: Nothing is wrong Bill, that's just how my teacher likes his homework problems. I just tried using `Reduce` just now, but something awful was spat at my face.

Comment: `Thread[{f1, f2, f3, f4} == 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, one can use the Weierstrass substitution. I will give a partial solution, and let the OP finish the task.

With the definitions above:

```
eqs = Thread[{f1, f2, f3, f4} == 0] /.
      Thread[{T1, T2} -> 2 ArcTan[{u1, u2}]] // TrigExpand // Simplify;
```

To ease things a bit, solve first for `r3` and `xB`:

```
ss = Solve[eqs, {r3, xB}, {u1, u2}] // FullSimplify // PowerExpand;
```

where for example we get the solution

```
Last[ss]
   {r3 -> Sqrt[1 + r1^2 + 2 r1 Sin[q]], xB -> (d Cos[q])/(r1 + Sin[q])}
```

To solve for e.g. `T1`, just plug any of the solutions in `ss` into the first equations in `eqs`, and then undo the substitution:

```
{T1 -> #} & /@ (2 ArcTan[u1] /. Simplify[Solve[First[eqs] /. Last[ss], u1]])
   {{T1 -> 2 ArcTan[(-Cos[q] + Sqrt[1 + r1^2 + 2 r1 Sin[q]])/(r1 + Sin[q])]},
    {T1 -> 2 ArcTan[(Cos[q] + Sqrt[1 + r1^2 + 2 r1 Sin[q]])/(r1 + Sin[q])]}}
```

so we see that there are two possible values of `T1` for each `{r3, xB}` pair. You can then use these to solve for `u2` (and thus `T2`).

Comment: Thank you man, that was right on the spot. I just solved the set of equations by using your method and learned a lot. You just saved a man's life.